# SQL Alchemy connection refused when trying to connect db and web containers

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I am having problem when running `docker-compose up` with my django/postgres app (using sqlalchemy).

Everything is fine when just running it localy but when i try to contenerise it(with Docker) I am having an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432`

For some reason app is not connecting to db.

My *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my database
      - POSTGRES_USER=my user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my password
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

My engine:

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://my user:my password@127.0.0.1:5432/my database")
```

Django settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'my database',
        'USER': 'my user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Can anyone advice where am I making mistake?

**EDIT**:

I tried Max's solution but nothing changed. I found out in error trackback that line where I use my engine is shown. So should I somehow modify my engine aswell?

Comment: You should connect your containers within a network. [See here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) Maybe you have also to adapt the database url to match the container name or ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to edit my comment again.

So first of all you need to combine your containers in one docker network, [see here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). An example docker-compose would look like that:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my database
      - POSTGRES_USER=my user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my password
    networks:
      - backend

  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend


networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    name: backend
```

Then you need to edit your django settings:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'my database',
        'USER': 'my user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my password',
        'HOST': '<your-service-name should be "db">',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

In your current settings, the django tries to connect to a database, that is running within in the same container, what is not the case.

Comment: I recreated all your suggestions putting in settings.py "HOST": "db", cleared all the images and started again and unfortunatelly nothing changed, still got same error.

Comment: I tried Your suggestion and it didn't work as same error is returned. I assume it may be sth wrong with the engine. Should I change url in there aswell to make it ?
engine = create_engine("postgresql://mu user:my password@db:5432/my database")

Comment: I am not familiar with the string of `create_engine`, what is the `mu` part of for?

Comment: sorry that's a typo it should be <"my user">

Comment: Okay, to check if you can access the docker-container DB from your python container, you try to connect inside your container with `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash `. And then try to ping the other container, either by service name or IP. You might need to install the ping package separately in your container.